# Picklist Field Values

Tags: picklist, record-type

I am trying to add new values for a picklist field and removing old values of that field from a specific Record Type only. Those old value will be active just removing from a specific record type. Does the removal of old values from particular record type will impact the records already available of that record type.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a picklist (`Status`) on `Account` with the following options

- Active
- Inactive
- Dropped

If you remove `Dropped` as an option for a specific record type (`Business`), the following will occur:

1. Existing Business Accounts with a `Dropped` status will still display it as the selected value. Once the user changes the status & saves, `Dropped` will no longer be available to select.
2. Existing Business Accounts without an existing `Dropped` status will no longer display that value as a selectable option

Removing a picklist value from a record type will remove it as a selectable options on records for that record type that have not selected it already. If that removed value was selected, it'll continue to display but will disappear once it's updated to another value.

Comment: Thanks @Kris Goncalves